# Digit summation of squared numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, computational-number-theory

In olympiad teaching period, we have a session that students must try to design a good problem for others. Many times we arrive to good questions but sometimes there are some challenges. In one of our exam we gave this problem to our students:

Find the 5-digit numbers that the summation of the digits of their square is maximum?
In the problem designing session, we got this problem (the notations are corrected and redefined. Also, I give here the generalized form of question):

Let $D_n^2(k)$ denotes the total number of $n$ digits number such that the summation of the digits of its square is less than or equal to $k$. What is the behaviour of $D_n^2(k)$?

I think this general form is so hard. Is the question famous or previously studied somewhere?
Is there any approximation for the values of $D_n^2(k)$ based on $n$ and $k$?

Comment: You might start by looking at the links at [OEIS sequence A004159](https://oeis.org/A004159).

Comment: This is loosely related to an early proposed (by Von Neumann) pseudo-random number generator [the Middle square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method), which would square an $n$ digit number (producing a $2n$ digit number), extract the middle $n$ digits, then iterate. Some cryptanalysis of this could theoretically be based on understanding the digits of the square of a number, but I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Dear Mark, I am familiar with that method which you mentioned.  But, I can not see how we can use it for this question!

Comment: Dear Israel, I did not find something there. Am I did wrong search?

Comment: Digits of squares are very difficult to control. That is why it is easy to formulate such problems and hard to solve them. For example an old unsolved (as far as I know) problem asks if  there are squares which are not powers of 10 and whose digits are 1 and 0.

Comment: Dear Mark Sapir, you are right. Is there any chances that for large $n$ we can assume identical distribution for digits in the squared numbers? Would you give any references for your claim and also for your conjecture?

Comment: I do not know reference. I tried to solve the problem 45 years ago.

Comment: Wow, I was not born 45 years ago. Anyway, thank you for your comment. I found some references for this conjecture.

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz You didn't find the links or you didn't find anything relevant in them?

Comment: @Robert Israel I did not find relevant thing!